# Javascript 2d tilemap without drawing all tiles

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, game-physics, tile

I am creating a 2D platformer in JavaScript. I am trying to create a tilemap that does not spawn in blocks where there is supposed to be air (labeled 0 in tilemap). I do not get any errors. However, no blocks are spawned in the canvas. The game also crashes unless i remove the collision detection.

Main js

```
//drawing variables
var canvas;
var context;

//game variables
var gameLoop;
var player;
var borders = [];
var mapHeight = 12;
var mapWidth = 22;
var tilesize = 50;

//input variables
var upKey;
var rightKey;
var downKey;
var leftKey;

//runs once pace has been loaded
window.onload = function(){
    //canvas and context variable setup
    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas")
    context = canvas.getContext("2d")

    //key listeners 
    setupInputs();

    //create player
    player = new Player(400, 400);

    //create border
    let tilemap = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    ]

    //create a box (border) based on tilemap position. Let 0's be air
    for (let row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++){
        for(let col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++){
            if(tilemap[row][col] !== 0){
                borders.push(new Border(tilemap[row]*tilesize, tilemap[col]*tilesize, tilesize, tilesize, tilemap[row][col]));
            }
        }
    }

    //initialize main game loop. Framerate = 30/sec
    gameLoop = setInterval(step, 1000/30);

    //draw canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#f4f4f4f4"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, mapWidth*tilesize, mapHeight*tilesize);
}

function step(){
    player.step();

    //draw after updates
    draw();
}

function draw(){
    //Clear previous canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#f4f4f4f4"
    context.fillRect(0, 0, mapWidth*tilesize, mapHeight*tilesize);

    //draw the player
    player.draw();

    //draw borders
    for(let i = 0; i < borders.length; i++){
        borders[i].draw();
    }
}

//keyboard inputs
function setupInputs(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
        if(event.key === "w"){
            upKey = true;
        } else if(event.key === "a"){
            leftKey = true;
        } else if(event.key === "s"){
            downKey = true;
        } else if(event.key === "d"){
            rightKey = true;
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        if(event.key === "w"){
            upKey = false;
        } else if(event.key === "a"){
            leftKey = false;
        } else if(event.key === "s"){
            downKey = false;
        } else if(event.key === "d"){
            rightKey = false;
        }
    });
}

//Checking to see if player and border intersect
function checkIntersection(r1, r2){
    if (r1.x >= r2.x + r2.width){
        return false;
    } else if (r1.x + r1.width <= r2.x){
        return false;
    } else if (r1.y >= r2.y + r2.height){
        return false;
    } else if (r1.y + r1.height <= r2.y){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Player js

```
function Player(x, y){
    //Player variables
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xvel = 0;
    this.yvel = 0;
    this.friction = 0.6;
    this.maxVel = 12;
    this.width = tilesize;
    this.height = tilesize;
    this.active = true;
    this.falling = false;


    this.step = function(){
        if(this.active){
            if(!leftKey && !rightKey || leftKey && rightKey){
                this.xvel *= this.friction;
            } else if (rightKey){
                this.xvel++;
            } else if (leftKey){
                this.xvel--;
            }

            if(upKey){
                //check if standing on ground
                if (this.yvel === 0 && this.falling === false){
                    this.yvel -= 70;
                    this.falling = true;
                } else{
                    this.yvel += 0;
                }
            }
            this.yvel += 1;

            //not allowing velocity to surpass maximum velocity
            if (this.xvel > this.maxVel){
                this.xvel = this.maxVel;
            } else if(this.xvel < -this.maxVel){
                this.xvel = -this.maxVel; 
            }
            if (this.yvel > this.maxVel){
                this.yvel = this.maxVel;
            } else if(this.yvel < -this.maxVel){
                this.yvel = -this.maxVel; 
            }
            if (this.xvel > 0){
                this.xvel = Math.floor(this.xvel);
            } else {
                this.xvel = Math.ceil(this.xvel);
            }
            if (this.yvel > 0){
                this.yvel = Math.floor(this.yvel);
            } else {
                this.yvel = Math.ceil(this.yvel);
            }

            //collision rectangles
            let horizontalRect = {
                x: this.x + this.xvel,
                y: this.y,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height
            }
            let verticalRect = {
                x: this.x,
                y: this.y + this.yvel,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height
            }
            //Collision deteQction
            for(let i = 0; i<borders.length; i++){
                let borderRect = {
                    x: borders[i].x,
                    y: borders[i].y,
                    width: borders[i].width,
                    height: borders[i].height
                }
                if (checkIntersection(horizontalRect, borderRect)){
                    while (checkIntersection(horizontalRect, borderRect)){
                        horizontalRect.x -= Math.sign(this.xvel);
                    }
                    this.x = horizontalRect.x;
                    this.xvel = 0;
                }
                if (checkIntersection(verticalRect, borderRect)){
                    while(checkIntersection(verticalRect, borderRect)){
                        verticalRect.y -= Math.sign(this.yvel);
                    }
                    this.y = verticalRect.y;
                    this.yvel = 0;
                    this.falling = false;
                }
            }
            if (this.x + this.xvel > mapWidth*tilesize - tileisze){
                this.xvel = 0;
            }
            if (this.x + this.xvel < 0){
                this.xvel = 0;
            }
            
            this.x += this.xvel;
            this.y += this.yvel;
        }
    }

    this.draw = function(){
        context.fillStyle = "orange";
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Border js

```
function Border(x, y, width, height, type){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.type = type;

    this.draw = function(){
        if (this.type === 1){
            context.fillStyle = "#2C2C34";
        } else if (this.type === 2){
            context.fillStyle = "#39393A";
        }
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be several errors in your code and it may take a while to find them all. You hex colors have 8 characters `"#f4f4f4f4"`. You have a map width of 22 but only have 21 columns in the 2D array. It also seems off that when you are creating your borders array you have `rows` in the `x` spot and `col` in the `y` spot. I seems like it should be reversed. Anyway if you're not opposed to using a 1D array here is a simplified version of you code without the player stuff.

Border

```
function Border(type, x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = TILE_SIZE;
    this.height = TILE_SIZE;
    this.type = type;

    this.draw = function(){
        if (this.type === 1){
            context.fillStyle = "purple";
            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        } else if (this.type === 2){
            context.fillStyle = "orange";
            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
}
```

and the main file

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
const TILE_SIZE = 25; //50 was too big for my screen based on how many rows/columns you wanted
canvas.width = 525; //TILE_SIZE * columns
canvas.height = 300; //TILE_SIZE * rows

var borders = [];

let tileMap = {
    mapHeight: 12,
    mapWidth: 21,
    size: TILE_SIZE,
    grid: [
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    ]
}
//Uses 1 loop to create the grid
function createGrid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < tileMap.grid.length; i++) {
        let x = (i % tileMap.mapWidth) * tileMap.size;
        let y = Math.floor((i / tileMap.mapWidth)) * tileMap.size;
        let type = tileMap.grid[i];
        borders.push(new Border(type, x, y));
    }
};
createGrid(); //creates the grid when file is loaded

function animate() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(let i = 0; i < borders.length; i++){
        borders[i].draw();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate()
```

I stuck the for loop in the animate function only for this example. Normally it would be its own function and that is where you can handle collision detection or drawing tiles or anything else you want to do with them.

If you must use a 2d array here is a function that will create it

```
function createGrid() {
   for (let row = 0; row < tileMap.mapHeight; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < tileMap.mapWidth; col++) {
       let type = tileMap.grid[row][col];
       let x = col * TILE_SIZE;
       let y = row * TILE_SIZE;
       borders.push(new Border(type, x, y))
    }
   }
}
createGrid()
```

Be sure to change the map back to 2d if you use the one I posted above. I also noticed in your player file you have  `tileisze` at one point instead of `tilesize`. I would take some time to carefully scrub your files for errors as these may be the cause of some of your problems.